# Excel Formula that returns and joins multiple values when using wildcard

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling to find an answer for this theres so many limitations I cant get passed.

**I have data in col A that would look like this**

```
dgsjhsks1234.uk
kjfkljdmlkdm23.UK
djfhsdjfhsdkjfh.UK
```

**In col B there is a string of data an example of what colB would look like**

```
dgsjhsks1234.uk, sdfsdfsdf324.uk, xfcvxcverv3234.uk
sdflaksdmnfasdk.uk, kjfkljdmlkdm23.UK, jkhdakjsdhakjsdh.uk
alksdjalskdm.uk, alsjdaoucnqonqwo.uk, djfhsdjfhsdkjfh.UK
```

Col B has a range like this of say 500 rows.

**What I need**

I want to look for whatever is in cell A2 then search through range B:B. When a match is found it returns an adjacent value from Col C

This can be done with Xlookup however Xlookup cant return multiple values

I normally would do a text join with an IF statement and separate the values by a comma but since its not an exact match I'm really stuck. Every turn I take is a dead end. Countif, Search and several other options I havent been able to get working.

Comment: `=FILTER($C$1:$C$500,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,$B$1:$B$500)))`?

Comment: It looks like Scott Craner fixed it before I could does that help? The format when I hit post got messed up then I had to close the browser to log back in and fix it.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think that did it!!!!! Thank you!  One minor problem the places where there are duplicate entries I get a #SPILL error. It wants to drop the multiple entries down a level but theres the data from the next row. Is there any way to make the over flow go to the right not down

Comment: `=TRANPOSE(FILTER($C$1:$C$500,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,$B$1:$B$500))))`

Comment: That did it thank you so much. I spent hours on this today. I really appreciate your help @scott